# PowerShell ThrowTerminatingError() errors are not true terminating errors

Tags: powershell

This is either a bug report prelude or a question about the design logic and usefulness.
And in any case, a question on how to develop cmdlets with true terminating errors.

In a clean session, i.e. with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'` and without
`try` or `trap`, invoke any of the following commands (or even all together):

```
# script module, missing path
Save-Module InvokeBuild -Path zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'

# cmdlet, invalid data
ConvertFrom-Json zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'

# cmdlet, invalid command syntax
Get-Module -Name zzz -FullyQualifiedName zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'
Export-Csv -Path zzz -LiteralPath zzz -InputObject 1 -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'
```

As a result, `'Continued!'` is invoked after each command that uses `ThrowTerminatingError()`.
It turns out this method terminates the command itself but not the calling script.

These are just a few contrived examples, there are many others.
Examples are not real but the issue bites for real sometimes.

Note that `-ErrorAction Stop` does not help, it is not designed for such errors.
It affects non-terminating errors (`WriteError()`, `Write-Error`).

---

And the practical question: is there a way to emit a terminating error which is
terminating for the current command and the calling script?

It looks like in scripts this will do (in some cases, not all):

```
Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop "message"
```

Note that `throw "message"` is really terminating.
But there is important difference from `Write-Error` and `ThrowTerminatingError()`.
Its error location points to the line of `throw`. This is not always as useful as
the line with the failing command invocation, especially on syntax or
input issues, i.e. terminating issues by nature.

So scripts have something. But what can cmdlets do?
Available `WriteError()` is not terminating.
Raw `throw` is not much different from `ThrowTerminatingError()`.

---

**UPDATE**

Indeed, `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` makes `ThrowTerminatingError()` terminating in the calling script. So do `try` and `trap`.

This is not what I am looking for. I specifically noted `$ErrorActionPreference
= 'Continue'`, *the default*. I am looking for absolute terminating errors
regardless if the default settings. Compare, in scripts `throw` is always
terminating (though it is not perfect, as mentioned). I am looking for the
analogue in .NET cmdlets.

Users forget to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. I forget this sometimes.
And some cases like invalid commands should stop the calling script regardless
of settings. At least command authors should be able to choose this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw the same exception as `throw` statement in PowerShell throw:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Throw")]
    public class TestThrow : Cmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Message") { WasThrownFromThrowStatement=true };
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru|Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module

Test-Throw; 'Not printed'
```

In scripts it can be done in this way (requires calling internal method):

```
function Test-ScriptThrow {
    $ErrorRecordType = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
    $ErrorRecord = $ErrorRecordType::new([Exception]::new("Message"), 'ErrorId', 'NotSpecified', $null)
    $ErrorRecordType.InvokeMember('SetInvocationInfo', 'Instance, NonPublic, InvokeMethod', $null, $ErrorRecord, $MyInvocation)
    throw $ErrorRecord
}

Test-ScriptThrow; 'Not printed'
```

It seems that same thing is necessary for C# cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Throw2")]
    public class TestThrow2 : PSCmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            ErrorRecord errorRecord = new ErrorRecord(new Exception("Message"), "ErrorId", ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, null);
            typeof(ErrorRecord).InvokeMember("SetInvocationInfo", BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, errorRecord, new[] { MyInvocation });
            throw new RuntimeException(null, null, errorRecord) { WasThrownFromThrowStatement=true };
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru|Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module

Test-Throw2 | % { Some other command }; 'Not printed'
```

Otherwise it underline whole statement as error, not only one command:

```
Test-Throw | % { Some other command }; 'Not printed'
```

Comment: It looks like a possible answer. Let me try it in various scenarios.

Comment: It's a pity that `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` is still not terminating
with this trick that works for .NET cmdlets. It would be nice to find a
solution, too. Any magic ideas?

Comment: @RomanKuzmin It possible for scripts, but it requires to use internal methods.

Comment: If if it is not too nasty, it would be interesting to know. At least for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> As a result, 'Continued!' is invoked after each command that uses `ThrowTerminatingError()`. It turns out this method terminates the command itself but not the calling script.

Of course not - your `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `Continue` - so when a cmdlet invocation throws an error, the repl (or script) simply resumes (**continue**s) execution.

`$ErrorActionPreference` is local to the scope in which it is defined, so you can set it inside a function or script to override the user's preference (but only within the scope of the function/script):

#### script.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# script module, missing path
Save-Module InvokeBuild -Path zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'

# cmdlet, invalid data
ConvertFrom-Json zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'

# cmdlet, invalid command syntax
Get-Module -Name zzz -FullyQualifiedName zzz -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'
Export-Csv -Path zzz -LiteralPath zzz -InputObject 1 -ErrorAction Stop; 'Continued!'
```

It'll return immediately after the error from `Save-Module` (even if `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `Continue` in the calling scope)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I specifically mentioned `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'`.
I am looking for absolute terminating errors regardless if the default settings.
For example, in scripts `throw` is always terminating.
I am looking for the analogue in .NET cmdlets.

Comment: Users forget to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. I forget this sometimes. And some cases like invalid commands should stop the calling script regardless of settings. At least authours should be able to choose this option.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin You can set it inside any child scope without affecting the calling scope, see update to the answer

Comment: Personally, I think that current behaviour is a bug or design flaw. Before submitting this as a bug or a suggestion I would like to ask about the reasoning or usefulness of such a design.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin Reason is very simple - security. By allowing the author of a piece of code to exit the callers scope, you've subverted the users control, bad idea

Comment: And god knows what it allows if an invalid command does not stop, as users normally expect. Please look at the examples, these are bugs in code, like C# would not even compile in *some* similar cases.

Comment: What would you expect your code to do? Exit from the console? What good would that do? Terminating errors terminate script execution and can be caught by `try`/`catch` in the console. AFAICS that's what reasonably could be expected from an interpreted language.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, I expect `ThrowTerminatingError()` (or some other method) to work the same way as `throw` in scripts does (only with different error position info). `throw` in scripts does not exit the console.

Comment: FYI. See [help about_preference_variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796(v=wps.620).aspx): "Neither $ErrorActionPreference nor the ErrorAction common parameter affect how Windows PowerShell responds to terminating errors (those that stop cmdlet processing).". Thus, either help is wrong or ThrowTerminatingError() is not terminating because $ErrorActionPreference affects how PowerShell responds.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I felt like I needed to downvote the answer and add a comment. PowerShell's error handling mechanism is appalling and inconsistent and something that has been discussed for a long time by big supporters of PowerShell including PowerShell MVPs like Jaykul. Although your answer is "correct", it is only half correct and doesn't really address what the OP asked and only scratches the surface. The fact is that `PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` is inconsistent and nonsensical, as much of PowerShell's error handling mechanism is.

Comment: Also, although I (partially) agree with you in that allowing a piece of code to exit the callers scope could be bad, that actually happens in PowerShell. Just use `throw` and all of a sudden the whole script is terminated (if not caught). It also happens in pretty much every other programming language ever built. If you have an exception and you don't catch it ... ever ... then it will blow the program up because you have an unhandled exception. Why should PowerShell be different? I only agree that it could be bad *if* the caller doesn't have the possibility to change that behaviour